# Package restore failed VS 17 for MySql

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual studio 2017 and I wish to create a Web API. I want to use MySql as my database.

My .csproj looks like following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For MySql I went into NuGet package manager and searchedfor mysql.data which shows me the latest stable version to be 6.9.9. When I try to install it, I get `Package restore failed` error.

Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:** I was also referring to http://insidemysql.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-and-mysql-connectornet/ this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`